# Can't assign the proper array values in forEach

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

i recently came into a weird(for me) behaviour.

```
 let test = [
    { id: 1, name: 'test1' },
    { id: 2, name: 'test2' },
    { id: 3, name: 'test3' }
]
let test2 = []
test.forEach((elem, index) => {

    console.warn(elem, index);
    test2.push(elem.name)
    elem.arr = test2
})

console.warn(test);
```

and i want the expected outcome to be like this

```
[ { id: 1, name: 'test1', arr: [ 'test1'] },
  { id: 2, name: 'test2', arr: [ 'test1', 'test2'] },
  { id: 3, name: 'test3', arr: [ 'test1', 'test2', 'test3' ] }]
```

but i get this

```
[ { id: 1, name: 'test1', arr: [ 'test1', 'test2', 'test3'] },
  { id: 2, name: 'test2', arr: [ 'test1', 'test2', 'test3'] },
  { id: 3, name: 'test3', arr: [ 'test1', 'test2', 'test3'] }]
```

Can someone explain me why this is happening(probably something about references?) and a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's only a single `test2` array, referred to (via the `arr`) property three times in a row. All of these entries point back to a **single** array.

You probably wanted to take a copy:

```
elem.arr = [...test2]
```

```js
let test = [
    { id: 1, name: 'test1' },
    { id: 2, name: 'test2' },
    { id: 3, name: 'test3' }
]
let test2 = []
test.forEach((elem, index) => {

    //console.log(elem, index);
    test2.push(elem.name)
    elem.arr = [...test2]
})

console.log(JSON.stringify(test, null, 2));
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe what's happening is that the `arr` attribute for each element is being set equal to the `test2` reference, rather than copying in the contents of `test2` at that time.

More information here: [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language)

See also: [Copy array by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486085/copy-array-by-value)

Based on the second link, you need to create new arrays when assigning to `elem.arr`.

```
elem.arr = test2.slice();
```

[Update] @spender had a newer way to copy arrays I didn't know about (still catching up on ES6). See also: https://www.samanthaming.com/tidbits/35-es6-way-to-clone-an-array

Answer (score 1):

> probably something about references?

You are correct. The assignment does not make a copy of the value of `test2` into `elem.arr`
So after the operation is done. If you try to run `test2 = []`
All the `arr` property will be `[]`

If you wish to do so you can destructure just like spender's answer